# Ideal choice for a view which recognizes taps and can change its text/label?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, ios7

This question is for the iOS development platform.

I am looking for something that will have some text on it and will recognize taps. Once tapped, it will do some stuff and change the text on itself. (It will be a part of a game like app).

At first I considered using a UIButton with a custom image. But on trying to change the text on it, I realized that it is read-only.

Then I considered using a UILabel, but it didn't suit my use as, at a later stage, I would like to make the View have a custom shape with an outline.

Right now, I am considering adding a generic UIView and add a Label as a subView to it. (Can I give the UIView a custom shape?)

Please can someone point out a better solution or if I am wrong above.

Comment: `UIButton`'s title isn't read only. You can use `setTitle:forState:` method.

Comment: I want some new text to be generated and update the text on the button for the normal state, every time someone taps it. Can that be done with the method you suggested?

Comment: Yes you can, that's the purpose of the method. Check bottom of this document for the available states. [UIControl Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIControlStateNormal)

Comment: Thank you! I had read that method description but didn't understand their wording. Tried it, and it worked just as I expected. Thanks again. :)
Just wondering if I choose custom and set a circular image, then what will happen if the player taps outside the circle but within the containing square?

Comment: If you have found the answer to this question, please add it as an answer (and only an answer) to this question. There is no need to edit your question to include the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Desdenova said, his solution worked for me.

**UIButton's title isn't read only. You can use setTitle:forState: method.**

Answer (score 0):

For creating custom shaped objects use UIbezierPath. Through UIbezierPath we can create custom shaped UIViews. Touch inside those views can handle adding gestures to that views.

Sample:-

```
UIBezierPath* path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width, 0)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width, [self headerBackGroundView].frame.size.height)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];

[path setLineWidth:1.0];

[[UIColor lightGrayColor] setStroke];

[path stroke];
```